# Gradient of composition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Consider a function $g: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x) := \langle a,x \rangle = a_{1}x_{1}+ ....+ a_{n}x_{n}$, for some $a \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then consider the function $\phi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the property that $$\frac{d \phi(z)}{d z} = \frac{1}{2}$$
How would you evaluate $\nabla \phi(g(x))$?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\nabla \phi(g(x))=\phi'(g(x))\nabla g(x)=\frac{1}{2} \vec{a}$$

For each component $x_i$
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_i}=\phi'(g(x)) \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}=\frac{1}{2}a_i$$

Comment: Thanks for your response. How exactly did you use the chain rule to obtain this?

Comment: This is the chain rule. I can edit it to show the details of the components.